# How to communicate with java code in PHP

Tags: java, php, php-java-bridge

G' Day,

I have a requirement, where need to invoke java function in PHP script. I have been gone through PHP JAVA Bridge concept but not able to call from PHP script. May be my Process was wrong. Please find the below process what i have been implemented.

1. ***step -1*** 
    C:\xampp\htdocs\tomcat\webapp Need to pest JavaBridge.war
   in this webapp.
2. ***step - 2*** 
    Extract this (JavaBridge.war) file. then go to
   JavaBridge/WEB-INF/lib/ and copy below three files and pest into 
   C:\xampp\htdocs\tomcat\webapp\bin

   php-script.jar php-servlet.jar servlet_api.jar
3. ***Step -3***
   Edit the Tomcat conf/web.xml. Add the following 9 lines
   marked with a +:

   ```
       + <listener><listener-class>php.java.servlet.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class></listener>
       + <servlet><servlet-name>PhpJavaServlet</servlet-name><servlet-class>php.java.servlet.PhpJavaServlet</servlet-class>
       + </servlet>
       + <servlet><servlet-name>PhpCGIServlet</servlet-name><servlet-class>php.java.servlet.fastcgi.FastCGIServlet</servlet-class>
       + <init-param><param-name>prefer_system_php_exec</param-name><param-value>On</param-value></init-param>
       + <init-param><param-name>php_include_java</param-name><param-value>Off</param-value></init-param>
       + </servlet>
       + <servlet-mapping><servlet-name>PhpJavaServlet</servlet-name><url-pattern>*.phpjavabridge</url-pattern>
   ```

   + PhpCGIServlet*.php
           ...
4. step - 4
   Start Tomcat again. Now you can add PHP scripts to tomcat.
5. step - 5 Add a PHP test file

   ```
   <?php require_once("java/Java.inc");
   echo java("java.lang.System")->getProperties(); ?>
   ```

   to some web context, for example "examples", and browse to
   http://yourHost.com:8080/examples/test.php.

***Its working fine but when i am run this file in htdocs (http://yourHost.com/test.php) its throwing exceptions.***

Please suggest me if i have been implemented wrong process or let me know if any new interface will work through this problem.

I do appreciate for Adv help.

Comment: What are the exceptions?

Comment: Thank you @MattWilson I will get you soon

Comment: Warning: require_once(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\testjava.php on line 2

Warning: require_once(http://localhost:8080/JavaBridge/java/Java.inc): failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\testjava.php on line 2

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'http://localhost:8080/JavaBridge/java/Java.inc' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\testjava.php on line 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to set your php.ini to allow url includes. [The docs](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php).

Comment: Thank you. I am working on that, once it will work fine let you know